# reaching specific element repeat Custom Fiends

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

How can i reach true css to a specific content repeat of Advance custom Fields? por ejemple the number one is .class:first-child and the last one is team_one_thrid:last-child but wat about the 3º??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
$i = 0;
while(have_rows('repeater_field')){
    the_row();
    $i++;

    ?><div class="item<?php echo $i; ?>">
        <!-- class item1, item2, item3... -->
    </div><?php
}
```

Increment a variable `$i` and use it in html tags.

Answer (score 1):

after reading some manuals find out the :span:nth-child(2n+1) that you can reach easily too any number of a row repeteat.